# Setup a redirection in IIS with parameters carried over

Tags: iis, redirect, iis-7, https, iis-6

If I have a website like the following:

```
https://xxx/section1/
https://xxx/section2/
https://xxx/section3/
```

But users may also access the URLs with parameters:

```
https://xxx/section1/&p=1494943
```

I'm going to create a seperate site in IIS6 which will redirect any HTTP requests to the HTTPS website:

```
request: http://xxx/
redirected to: https://xxx/
```

And in the same sense:

```
request: http://xxx/section2/&p=1474724
redirected to: https://xxx/section2/&p=1474724
```

My question is, how can I ensure they are redirected to the correct section and still carry over the parameters?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the $Q flag in the redirect URL, the request/query parameters should be included in the redirect from the original.  If you don't want the question mark to be included in the redirect URl, then use $P instead.

examples:
using `$Q`:
Original URL:  `http://startingURL?param1=1&param2=2`
Redirect URL:  `https://newURL$Q`
Resulting URL:  `https://newURL?param1=1&param2=2`

using `$P`:
Original URL:  `http://startingURL?param1=1&param2=2`
Redirect URL:  `https://newURL$P`
 
Resulting URL:  `https://newURLparam1=1&param2=2`

For additional reading, take a look at the TechNet article:  http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/41c238b2-1188-488f-bf2d-464383b1bb08.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when moving a DokuWiki instance from one server to another and then wanted to set up a HTTP redirect so it would redirect request from e.g.:

```
https://bananas.tycoon.ex/doku.php?id=knowledgebase:iis
```

...to:

```
https://oranges.tycoon.ex/doku.php?id=knowledgebase:iis
```

I tried a variety of things before I found a working solution for this. Here is the web.config configuration that finally achieved the desired result:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://oranges.tycoon.ex$S$Q" exactDestination="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The final important part was the [exactDestination="true"]. Without this, I was instead redirected to:

```
https://oranges.tycoon.ex/doku.php?id=knowledgebase:iis/doku.php
```

...which naturally landed me on a nonexisting page of the wiki thanks to the extra appended "/doku.php".